# Faster lookup between two dataframe columns - Python/Pandas Way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

I have two data frames  with each having about 250K lines. I am trying to do a fuzzy lookup between the two data frame's columns. After look up I need the indexes for those good matches with the threshold.

Some details are following,

My `df1`:

```
   Name     State      Zip        combined_1
0  Auto     MN            10      Auto,MN,10 
1  Rtla     VI           253      Rtla,VI,253  
2  Huka     CO         56218      Huka,CO,56218
3  kann     PR           214      Kann,PR,214
4  Himm     NJ         65216      Himm,NJ,65216
5  Elko     NY         65418      Elko,NY,65418
6  Tasm     MA            13      Tasm,MA,13
7  Hspt     OH         43218      Hspt,OH,43218
```

My other data frame that I am trying to look upto

```
   Name     State      Zip        combined_2
0  Kilo     NC         69521      Kilo,NC,69521 
1  Kjhl     FL          3369      Kjhl,FL,3369
2  Rtla     VI         25301      Rtla,VI,25301
3  Illt     GA         30024      Illt,GA,30024
4  Huka     CO         56218      Huka,CO,56218
5  Haja     OH         96766      Haja,OH,96766
6  Auto     MN           010      Auto,MN,010
7  Clps     TX         44155      Clps,TX,44155
```

If you look close, when I do fuzzy lookup I should get a good match for indexes 0 and 2 in my `df1` from `df2` indexes, 6, 4.

So, I did this,

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
# Save df1 index
df_1index = []

# save df2 index
df2_indexes = []

# save fuzzy ratio
fazz_rat = []

for index, details in enumerate(df1['combined_1']):
    for ind, information in enumerate(df2['combined_2']):
        fuzmatch = fuzz.ratio(str(details), str(information))
        if fuzmatch >= 94:
            df_1index.append(index)
            df2_indexes.append(ind)
            fazz_rat.append(fuzmatch)

        else:
            pass
```

As I expected, I am getting the results for this example case,

```
df_1index
>> [0,2]

df2_indexes
>> [6,4]
```

To run against 250K * 250K lines in both data frames it takes, so much time.

How can I speed up this lookup process? Is there pandas or python way to improve performance for what want?

Comment: This is a difficult problem. Perhaps consider pruning unnecessary comparisons, that is, name and zip might be different, but is there any reason to suspect the 2 character state is incorrect, or that you'd want to match MA with MN anyway? Exact match on state and only search within state, could save up to a factor of 50.

Comment: @ALollz thank you for the note. After some reading, my way seems to be an exponential growth in complexity. I agree that Name and Zip is enough, however, if all three attributes (name, state and zip) in the same column why does it reduce it by 50?  For my purposes I like the 3 in case if there is a mistake in state abbreviation.

Comment: Assuming each state has an equal share, you'd go from doing 250K * 250K comparisons to 50 (250K/50 x 250K/50) comparisons, which is 1/50 of your original number of comparisons. Of course, this is the best case scenario, if one state has many more observations than the others, then the gain isn't as large.

Comment: @ALollz Agreed. thank you for the clarification.